# I have to validate a date input if it is in mm/dd/yyyy format in C#

Tags: c#

I have date field in my Windows form and that is a user input. I need to validate if that date input is in mm/dd/yyyy format and need to throw an error if it is not. How Do I do that. I have no idea how to do that.

Please help.

Comment: Try looking up the documentation for `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do the trick:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out date))
{
   // Date is valid
}
```